# Is it possible to look up distances between AWS data centers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, high-availability, disaster-recovery

My company is negotiating with a customer who has requirements for a minimum distance between data centers. Namely they require redundant storage in data centers more than 3 km apart.

Is it possible to ensure this by using two different AZs in one AWS region (Frankfurt, if possible)?

I have searched around the internet for a while, but all I found are generic descriptions about AWS Region and AZ architecture without any specification about the geographic distance between data centers forming AZs and regions.

[The FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/?nc1=h_ls) only state that AZ's are

> physically separate, such that even extremely uncommon disasters such
>   as fires, tornados or flooding would only affect a single Availability
>   Zone

But I can't find anything more specific than that.

Answer (score 2):

AWS DC's are based in non-descriptive locations hence you will not be able to get any more details than FAQ. Having said that due to availability factor we can assume these AZ's would be located at a distant, however that's assumption only not supported by evidences.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this wikileaks map:
https://wikileaks.org/amazon-atlas/map/